# Get SignalrR ConnectionId on ClientSide (Angular App)

Tags: asp.net-core-signalr

Hi I'm using an angular app to connect to signalr, I am using  "@aspnet/signalr": "1.0.0-preview1-final".

I need to send the connectionId to my controller (I need to do some process and tell all others clients but no the user making the request), the problem is Connection Id is private, there is a way to get  the connection Id?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

## Tell all other clients (problem X)

Hub:

```cs
public async Task TellAllOtherClients(object[] args)
{
    await Clients.Others.SendAsync("method", args);
}
```

## Get `connectionId` (solution Y)

Hub:

```cs
public string GetConnectionId()
{
    return Context.ConnectionId;
}
```

Client:

```js
hub.invoke('getConnectionId')
    .then(function (connectionId) {
        // Send the connectionId to controller
    });
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer I will implement the solution proposed to tell another clients via hub method just after the controller responds.

Answer (score 4):

From Javascript...
Just interrogate the connection id property of the SignalR connection once a connection is made (in the `start().done` function). Like this:

```
var connectionid = _signalconnection.connection.connectionId;
```

Just be sure to do this in both the `start().done` and the `onreconnected` event.
That allows you to get the updated connectionid if it changes on a reconnect.

Pretty straightforward.

Here's my connection start statement, in case it helps...

```
    _signalconnection.start().then(function ()
    {
        console.log("Setup_SignalR: connection open.");
        
        // Get the connectionID...
        _connectionid = _signalconnection.connection.connectionId;
        
        // Make a log entry that is page contextual...
        var page = window.location.pathname;
        console.log("Setup_SignalR:ConnectionOpen for page (" + page + ") with connectionID = " + _connectionid);
        
    }).catch(function (err)
    {
        console.error("Setup_SignalR: connection failed. err = " + err);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Client:

```
let connection: signalR.HubConnection;
let accessToken = "3076a225-f2f6-4c68-b894-08accb62bb90";

connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("http://localhost:8178/notifyHub", { accessTokenFactory: () => accessToken }).build();
connection.start().then(function(){connection.invoke("GetConnectionId").then(function(connectionId){console.log(connectionId)})}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```